# Model Window Shows Same Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I'm making a dental website, this page I'm working on is for dental cases. So let's say there are three dental treatments, Dental Implants, Root Canal and Tooth Extraction. I'm developing something like, if someone clicks on Dental Implants, he can see a modal window, for the cases for that particular treatment. When he clicks on one of the cases, he can see a slideshow for that case. It works perfectly, but the only thing is that when I click on the dental implants or fracture case, I'm seeing the same modal window content. I found the code from [w3school's](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp) website. Is there any way I can have multiple modal windows with different content? Thanks so much.

[Screenshot of the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3mfy.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I have a large project that use what you want. I'll try to reduce other codes for you understand better. I'll need to include in your bootstrap plugin.

1) Bellow you'll see two pictures with initial image and after click on some image:
[image]

[image]

2) Html (I insert dynamically all of datas by jquery with request on a server):

```
   <div class="row content-side-imagem">
    <div id="fourth-slide" class="carousel slide" produto1-ini="0" produto1-fim="0" produto1-seq="0" produto1-qtpagina="0">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <div class="col-sm-4 fourth-slide-imagem" >
                    <a class="galeriaImagens" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#galeriaImagens" data-backdrop="false">
                       <img id="produto1-imagem1" src="" alt="" title=""   class="img-responsive center-block" >
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <p id="produto1-legenda1" class="fourth-slide-legenda">
                            </p>
                            <p id="produto1-item1">
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 fourth-slide-imagem" >
                    <a class="galeriaImagens" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#galeriaImagens" data-backdrop="false">
                       <img id="produto1-imagem2" src="" alt="" title=""   class="img-responsive center-block" >
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <p id="produto1-legenda2" class="fourth-slide-legenda">
                            </p>
                            <p id="produto1-item2">
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 fourth-slide-imagem" >
                    <a class="galeriaImagens" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#galeriaImagens" data-backdrop="false">
                        <img id="produto1-imagem3" src="" alt="" title=""   class="img-responsive center-block" >
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <p id="produto1-legenda3" class="fourth-slide-legenda">
                            </p>
                            <p id="produto1-item3">
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slides-control">
            <a title="Imagem Anterior" id="tras-produto1-slide" class="carousel-control" href="#fourth-slide" data-slide="prev">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>
            </a>
            <a title="Imagem Posterior" id="frente-produto1-slide" class="direita carousel-control" href="#fourth-slide" data-slide="next">
                <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="galeriaImagens" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <div class="numSlide5">
                <p class="numSlide5Texto text-center"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="carousel slide" id="fith-slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item">
                        <img id="slide5-imagem1" alt="" title="" src=""  class="img-responsive center-block">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <div id="slide5-legenda1" class="fith-slide-legenda">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slides-control">
                    <a title="Imagem Anterior" id="tras-slide5-slide" class="carousel-control" href="#fith-slide" data-slide="prev">
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>
                    </a>
                    <a title="Imagem Posterior" id="frente-slide5-slide" class="direita carousel-control" href="#fith-slide" data-slide="next">
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

3) jquery (call for first line carousel and for the second inside modal)

```
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.galeriaImagens').click(function () {
            var descricaoLegenda = $(this).children('div.carousel-caption').children('.fourth-slide-legenda').text();
            var listaLegenda = $('#fith-slide').children('.carousel-inner').children('.item')
                .children('.carousel-caption').children('.fith-slide-legenda');
            $('#fith-slide').find('.item.active').removeClass('active');
            $.each(listaLegenda, function (index, value) {
                if (descricaoLegenda == value.innerText)
                {
                    var selecao = value;
                    $(selecao).parents('.item').addClass('active');
                }
            });
            var totalItems = $('#fith-slide .item').length;
            var currentIndex = $('#fith-slide div.active').index() + 1;
            $('.numSlide5Texto').html('' + currentIndex + '/' + totalItems + '');
            $('#fith-slide').bind('slid', function () {
                currentIndex = $('#fith-slide div.active').index() + 1;
                $('.numSlide5Texto').html('' + currentIndex + '/' + totalItems + '');
            });
        });

        // slide 1 - imagens
        var urlDestino = "";
        var idEnvio = 0;
        var nrReg = 0;
        var idProduto = 0;
        var frente = "S";
        function slide1() {
            $.ajax({
                url: urlDestino,
                type: "POST",
                data: { "id": idEnvio, "idProduto": idProduto, "nrRegistro": nrReg },
                async: true,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (document.getElementById("fourth-slide").getAttribute("produto1-ini") == 0) {
                        if (data.lista.length == 0 || data.lista == "0") {
                            $('#fotos-imovel').hide();
                            $('.fotos-imovel-icone').hide();
                        }
                    }
                    if (data.lista.length == 0)
                        return;
                    if (data == "") {
                        return;
                    }
                    var i = data.lista.length;
                    if (i > 0) {
                        i = i - 1;
                    }
                    var item = document.getElementById("fourth-slide").getAttribute("produto1-seq");
                    if (frente == "N") {
                        var qtdPagina = document.getElementById("fourth-slide").getAttribute("produto1-qtpagina");
                        qtdPagina = parseInt(qtdPagina);
                        item = item - (3 + qtdPagina);
                    }

                    if (i == 2) {
                        item++;
                        $('#produto1-item1').html(item + " / " + data.qtd);
                        $('#produto1-legenda1').html(data.lista[0].Descricao);
                        $('#produto1-imagem1').attr("src", data.lista[0].EnderecoImagem);
                        $('#produto1-imagem1').attr("title", data.lista[0].Descricao);
                        $('#produto1-imagem1').attr("alt", data.lista[0].DescricaoAlternativa);
                        $('#produto1-imagem1').attr("width", data.lista[0].Largura);
                        $('#produto1-imagem1').attr("height", data.lista[0].Altura);
                        item++;
                        $('#produto1-item2').html(item + " / " + data.qtd);
                        $('#produto1-legenda2').html(data.lista[1].Descricao);
                        $('#produto1-imagem2').attr("src", data.lista[1].EnderecoImagem);
                        $('#produto1-imagem2').attr("title", data.lista[1].Descricao);
                        $('#produto1-imagem2').attr("alt", data.lista[1].DescricaoAlternativa);
                        $('#produto1-imagem2').attr("width", data.lista[1].Largura);
                        $('#produto1-imagem2').attr("height", data.lista[1].Altura);
                        item++;
                        $('#produto1-item3').html(item + " / " + data.qtd);
                        $('#produto1-legenda3').html(data.lista[2].Descricao);
                        $('#produto1-imagem3').attr("src", data.lista[2].EnderecoImagem);
                        $('#produto1-imagem3').attr("title", data.lista[2].Descricao);
                        $('#produto1-imagem3').attr("alt", data.lista[2].DescricaoAlternativa);
                        $('#produto1-imagem3').attr("width", data.lista[2].Largura);
                        $('#produto1-imagem3').attr("height", data.lista[2].Altura);
                        $('#produto1-imagem1').parent().show();
                        $('#produto1-imagem2').parent().show();
                        $('#produto1-imagem3').parent().show();
                        $('#fourth-slide').attr('produto1-ini', data.lista[0].IdImagem);
                        $('#fourth-slide').attr('produto1-fim', data.lista[2].IdImagem);
                        $('#fourth-slide').attr('produto1-seq', item);
                        $('#fourth-slide').attr('produto1-qtpagina', 3);
                    }
                    else if (i == 1) {
                        item++;
                        $('#produto1-item1').html(item + " / " + data.qtd);
                        $('#produto1-legenda1').html(data.lista[0].Descricao);
                        $('#produto1-nome1').text(data.lista[0].NomeclienteProduto);
                        $('#produto1-imagem1').attr("src", data.lista[0].EnderecoImagem);
                        $('#produto1-imagem1').attr("title", data.lista[0].Descricao);
                        $('#produto1-imagem1').attr("alt", data.lista[0].DescricaoAlternativa);
                        $('#produto1-imagem1').attr("width", data.lista[0].Largura);
                        $('#produto1-imagem1').attr("height", data.lista[0].Altura);
                        item++;
                        $('#produto1-item2').html(item + " / " + data.qtd);
                        $('#produto1-nome2').text(data.lista[1].NomeclienteProduto);
                        $('#produto1-imagem2').attr("src", data.lista[1].EnderecoImagem);
                        $('#produto1-imagem2').attr("title", data.lista[1].Descricao);
                        $('#produto1-imagem2').attr("alt", data.lista[1].DescricaoAlternativa);
                        $('#produto1-imagem2').attr("width", data.lista[1].Largura);
                        $('#produto1-imagem2').attr("height", data.lista[1].Altura);
                        $('#produto1-legenda2').html(data.lista[1].Descricao);
                        $('#produto1-imagem1').parent().show();
                        $('#produto1-imagem2').parent().show();
                        $('#produto1-imagem3').parent().hide();
                        $('#fourth-slide').attr('produto1-ini', data.lista[0].IdImagem);
                        $('#fourth-slide').attr('produto1-fim', data.lista[1].IdImagem);
                        $('#fourth-slide').attr('produto1-seq', item);
                        $('#fourth-slide').attr('produto1-qtpagina', 2);
                    }
                    else {
                        item++;
                        $('#produto1-item1').html(item + " / " + data.qtd);
                        $('#produto1-legenda1').html(data.lista[0].Descricao);
                        $('#produto1-nome1').text(data.lista[0].NomeclienteProduto);
                        $('#produto1-imagem1').attr("src", data.lista[0].EnderecoImagem);
                        $('#produto1-imagem1').attr("title", data.lista[0].Descricao);
                        $('#produto1-imagem1').attr("alt", data.lista[0].DescricaoAlternativa);
                        $('#produto1-imagem1').attr("width", data.lista[0].Largura);
                        $('#produto1-imagem1').attr("height", data.lista[0].Altura);
                        $('#produto1-imagem1').parent().show();
                        $('#produto1-imagem2').parent().hide();
                        $('#produto1-imagem3').parent().hide();
                        $('#fourth-slide').attr('produto1-ini', data.lista[0].IdImagem);
                        $('#fourth-slide').attr('produto1-fim', data.lista[0].IdImagem);
                        $('#fourth-slide').attr('produto1-seq', item);
                        $('#fourth-slide').attr('produto1-qtpagina', 1);
                    }
                  }
            });
        };
        if (document.getElementById("fourth-slide").getAttribute("produto1-ini") == 0) {
            frente = "S";
            idEnvio = 0;
            urlDestino = "/Produto/BuscaImagemFrente";
            nrReg = 3;
            idProduto = $('#IdProduto').val();
            slide1();
        }
        $('#frente-produto1-slide').on('click', function () {
            frente = "S";
            var idFim = document.getElementById("fourth-slide").getAttribute("produto1-fim");
            idEnvio = idFim;
            urlDestino = "/Produto/BuscaImagemFrente";
            nrReg = 3;
            idProduto = $('#IdProduto').val();
            slide1();
        });
        $('#tras-produto1-slide').on('click', function () {
            frente = "N";
            var idIni = document.getElementById("fourth-slide").getAttribute("produto1-ini");
            idEnvio = idIni;
            urlDestino = "/Produto/BuscaImagemTras";
            nrReg = 3;
            idProduto = $('#IdProduto').val();
            slide1();
        });
        $('#fourth-slide').carousel({
            interval: false
        });



        // slide 4 - imagens - galeria de imagens
        var urlDestino = "";
        var idProduto = 0;
        function slide4() {
            $.ajax({
                url: urlDestino,
                type: "POST",
                data: { "idProduto": idProduto },
                async: true,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data == "") {
                        return;
                    }
                    var i = data.length;
                    if (i > 0) {
                        i = i - 1;
                    }
                    var y = 0;
                    for (x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                        if (data[x].IdPostagemImagem == 3) {
                            y++;
                            if (y == 1) {
                                $('#slide5-legenda1').html(data[x].Descricao);
                                $('#slide5-imagem1').attr("src", data[x].EnderecoImagem);
                                $('#slide5-imagem1').attr("title", data[x].Descricao);
                                $('#slide5-imagem1').attr("alt", data[x].DescricaoAlternativa);
                            }
                            else {
                                $('#fith-slide .carousel-inner').append('<div class="item">' +
                                '<img alt="' + data[x].DescricaoAlternativa + '" title="' +
                                data[x].Descricao + '" src="' + data[x].EnderecoImagem + '" class="img-responsive center-block">' +
                                '<div class="carousel-caption"><div class="fith-slide-legenda">' +
                                data[x].Descricao + '</div></div></div>');
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            });
        };
        urlDestino = "/Produto/BuscaTodasImagens";
        idProduto = $('#IdProduto').val();
        slide4();
        $('#fith-slide').carousel({
            interval: false
        });

    });
```

4) Controller (with two calls from jquery):

```
        [HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> BuscaImagemFrente(int? id, int idProduto, int nrRegistro)
    {
        int qtdTot = await (from d in db.Imagem
                           join p in db.Produto on d.IdProduto equals p.IdProduto
                           where  p.IdProduto == idProduto
                                 && d.IdPostagemImagem == 3
                           select d.IdProduto).CountAsync();
        int dep = 0;
        if (id == 0)
        {
            dep = int.Parse((from d in db.Imagem
                  join p in db.Produto on d.IdProduto equals p.IdProduto
                  where  p.IdProduto == idProduto
                         && d.IdPostagemImagem == 3
                             orderby d.IdImagem
                             select d.IdImagem).FirstOrDefault().ToString());
            id = dep - 1;
        }
        if (id >= 0)
        {
            var frente = await (from d in db.Imagem
                          join p in db.Produto on d.IdProduto equals p.IdProduto
                          where d.IdImagem > id && p.IdProduto == idProduto
                                && d.IdPostagemImagem == 3
                                orderby d.IdImagem
                                select new
                          {
                              d.IdImagem,
                              d.IdProduto,
                              d.EnderecoImagem,
                              d.CorFundoLegenda,
                              d.Descricao,
                              d.IdEmpresa,
                              d.Largura,
                              d.Altura,
                              d.IdPostagemImagem,
                              d.DescricaoAlternativa,
                              d.DescricaoLegenda,
                              d.PosicaoHorizontalLegenda,
                              d.Detalhamento
                          })
                          .Take(nrRegistro).ToListAsync();
            return Json( new { lista = frente, qtd = qtdTot });
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(0);
        }
    }

            [HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> BuscaImagemTras(int? id, int idProduto, int nrRegistro)
    {
        int qtdTot = await (from d in db.Imagem
                           join p in db.Produto on d.IdProduto equals p.IdProduto
                           where   p.IdProduto == idProduto
                                 && d.IdPostagemImagem == 3
                           select d.IdProduto).CountAsync();
        if (id > 0)
        {
            var frente = await (from d in db.Imagem
                                join p in db.Produto on d.IdProduto equals p.IdProduto
                                where d.IdImagem < id && p.IdProduto == idProduto
                                && d.IdPostagemImagem == 3
                                orderby d.IdImagem descending
                                select new
                                {
                                    d.IdImagem,
                                    d.IdProduto,
                                    d.EnderecoImagem,
                                    d.CorFundoLegenda,
                                    d.Descricao,
                                    d.IdEmpresa,
                                    d.Largura,
                                    d.Altura,
                                    d.IdPostagemImagem,
                                    d.DescricaoAlternativa,
                                    d.DescricaoLegenda,
                                    d.PosicaoHorizontalLegenda,
                                    d.Detalhamento
                                })
                                  .Take(nrRegistro).OrderBy(x => x.IdImagem).ToListAsync();
            return Json(new { lista = frente, qtd = qtdTot });
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(0);
        }
    }
    public async Task<JsonResult> BuscaTodasImagens(int idProduto)
    {
        var retorno = await (from d in db.Imagem
                            join p in db.Produto on d.IdProduto equals p.IdProduto
                            where p.IdProduto == idProduto
                                    && (d.IdPostagemImagem == 3 || d.IdPostagemImagem == 9)
                            orderby d.IdPostagemImagem, d.IdImagem
                            select new
                            {
                                d.IdPostagemImagem,
                                d.EnderecoImagem,
                                d.Descricao,
                                d.DescricaoAlternativa,
                                d.DescricaoLegenda
                            })
                        .ToListAsync();
        return Json(retorno);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> BuscaDadosPlanta(int idProduto)
    {
        var frente = await (from d in db.Imagem
                        join p in db.Produto on d.IdProduto equals p.IdProduto
                        join e in db.EspecificacaoProduto on p.IdProduto equals e.IdProduto
                        where  p.IdProduto == idProduto && d.IdPostagemImagem == 9 &&
                              e.IdEspecificacaoProduto == d.IdEspecificacaoProduto
                            //orderby d.IdEspecificacaoProduto
                            orderby d.IdPostagemImagem, d.IdImagem
                            select new
                        {
                            e.IdEspecificacaoProduto,
                            e.DescricaoEspecificacaoProduto,
                            e.DetalhamentoEspecificacaoProduto,
                            d.IdImagem,
                            d.IdProduto,
                            d.EnderecoImagem,
                            d.CorFundoLegenda,
                            d.Descricao,
                            d.IdEmpresa,
                            d.Largura,
                            d.Altura,
                            d.IdPostagemImagem,
                            d.DescricaoAlternativa,
                            d.DescricaoLegenda,
                            d.PosicaoHorizontalLegenda,
                            d.Detalhamento
                        }).ToListAsync();
        return Json(frente);
    }
```

Comment: I did put different IDs. And I'd love to see the example.

Comment: Ok...when I get to my work an 1 hour I will send it.

Comment: That's it...I tried to reduce more that I could but with the entire project for you see. I think this can help you.

Comment: I can't thank you enough. I hope you have a nice day.

Comment: If this help you. .please check Up.